# Python Matplotlib create boxplot from data in mW, plot in dBm

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I have a set of data that contains an RSSI value in mW and a label of a device. See example data below.

My goal is to create a boxplot of average RSSI grouped by device label, but I'd like it to be printed in logarithmic dBm scale, instead of linear mW scale.

I have a function for the conversion:

```
def toDeciBellMilliWatt(RSSI):
    """Returns RSSI value in dBm, assuming input is mW"""
    return 10*math.log10(RSSI)
```

And this call can create the **boxplots** (please note, I'm after these because box and whiskers display quantiles, I'm not after plots) I need:

```
data.boxplot(column='RSSI', by='label')
```

but I'd like the y axis to be in dBm. Is there a way to achieve this directly after the call for boxplot has computed all quantiles? Have no idea where to start from

example data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label', 'RSSI'],
                    data=[['A', 1.99e-7],
                          ['B', 1.25e-9],
                          ['A', 1.99e-5],
                          ['A', 3.16e-7],
                          ['B', 3.16e-5],
                          ['A', 1.99e-7],
                          ['B', 3.91e-9],
                          ['A', 1.99e-5],
                          ['A', 3.14e-7],
                          ['B', 3.16e-5]])
```

---

**edit** to avoid confusion: the average on mW values converted to dBm is not equal to the average of dBm values. This is pretty easy to demonstrate on paper and is due to the fact that dBm is a log scale, while mW is not.

When computing the statistic values with a Boxplot in mW, we get the "correct" power average of the signal. Now, I'm missing the piece to show it in dBm so that technical people are able to understand it.

I could compute all the values myself, then assembly the boxplot from my calculations. What I'm after is a solution to convert the unit of measurement of the y axis of the entire boxplot created by Matplotlib into a log scale.

Comment: You would apply your function to the data and plot the new data. As simple as that.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, no it is not: the average on dBm is not equivalent to the average on mW. What I want is to average on mW, then convert the average to dBm: this is a far better approximation of power average.

Comment: A boxplot has no average in it, right? It's only the position in the dataset that matters. However, for outlier detection, or if you wanted to show the mean, it would actually matter indeed. Is that relevant in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to first draw the boxplot via pandas, then set the y-axis to logarithmic and change the formatting of the ticks. You could remove the minor ticks, as they are confusing with the new tick labels.

```py
import math
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def toDeciBellMilliWatt(RSSI):
    """Returns RSSI value in dBm, assuming input is mW"""
    return 10 * math.log10(RSSI)

def format_dBm(value, tick_number):
    return '–' + str(round(-toDeciBellMilliWatt(value)))

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label', 'RSSI'],
                    data=[['A', 1.99e-7],
                          ['B', 1.25e-9],
                          ['A', 1.99e-5],
                          ['A', 3.16e-7],
                          ['B', 3.16e-5],
                          ['A', 1.99e-7],
                          ['B', 3.91e-9],
                          ['A', 1.99e-5],
                          ['A', 3.14e-7],
                          ['B', 3.16e-5]])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
for ax in axes:
    data.boxplot(column='RSSI', by='label', ax=ax)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.25)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.minorticks_off()
axes[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(format_dBm))
plt.ylabel('RSSI (in dBm)')
plt.show()
```

At the left the original boxplot, at the center with y-tick-labels in dBm, at the right the version with the logarithmic ticks. The boxplot changes its visual aspect due to that logscale.

[image: example plot]